# tkinter open select folder option doesn't work in EC2

Tags: python, tkinter, amazon-ec2

I have written python 3 code in my windows machine to download a folder from s3. To get the the folder path where the files has to be saved locally, I have used tkinter to show a GUI.

I have copied the same code to my EC2 (ssh) machine (Ubuntu) and tried to run using Jupiter notebook and I got error as

```
no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

at

```
root = tk.Tk()
```

Is this anything due to OS change? If so how can I get a GUI to select a folder

```
 import tkinter as tk
 from tkinter import filedialog
 root = tk.Tk()
 root.withdraw()
 mydir = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

Comment: This is a very common error when you are logged on a remote machine and try to display things. It cannot find the display device.
First you must first make sure that you use one of the X11-based display back-ends.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common error when you are logged on a remote machine and try to display things. It cannot find the display device.

If you're using matplotlib as well, make sure that you use one of the X11-based display back-ends.

Are you using ssh to log in via a remote machine? If you're, try ssh to remote via

> ssh -X remoteMachineName